# Fetch api preflight request failing

Tags: javascript, http, cors, fetch-api

I'm trying to make a GET request from a public API but cant seem to figure out why the cors preflight request keeps failing.

```
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404
```

I've done some searching around and it seems like this is something that needs to be changed server side, but I just want to make sure there's nothing I might be doing wrong. I'm using the following code:

```
try {
  let guideData = await fetch(guideUrl, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${json.access_token}`,
    }
  });
} catch(err) {
  console.log("Failed to fetch data", err);
}
```

I've tested using Postman and Hurl, both seem to work fine, I just can't get it to work on my client.

Comment: Try `OPTIONS` method when doing hit from `POSTMAN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are sending http request from Postman and Curl the two don't behave like a web browser would. In your case you are using a web browser running js. The code itself looks fine minus the fact that you need to encode your token to make the Authorization work when sent.

The issue definitely seems to be server side, the gist is when you send `OPTIONS` it will tell you whether or not it's a problem with you or server. Most likely than not from the response you posted, it is definitely CORS.